# Using Libcurl library for file download

Tags: c++, winapi, libcurl

I am trying to implement autoupdate by downloading the update files from a share link in Dropbox or google drive. At first, I used windows API function URLDownloadToFile() to download public files from the web. It works fine, but when I used it for cloud files, it did not download the file. It rather get an HTML file that when opened with a browser, I can download the file using the browser.

So, I shifted to using Libcurl library and followed their tutorial. I always received error

> (60) : CURL_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION.

I followed the example at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html. And tried to get same public file I already downloaded the windows API and still received same error. So I know it is not related to server authentication or similar issues.

Here is my download function using both windows api and Libcurl:

```
static size_t write_data (void *ptr,size_t size,size_t nmemb,void* stream)
{
  size_t written = fwrite (ptr,size,nmemb,(FILE *) stream) ;
  return written ;
} /* write_data */


int DownloadFile ()
{
  static const char FileURL[] = "https://www.pexels.com/photo/618608/download/?search_query=park&tracking_id=6qgsqm6nzau" :
  static char TargetURL[]  = "D:\\Download\\DownloadURL\\Test.jpg" ;
  static char TargetCURL[] = "D:\\Download\\DownloadCURL\\Test.jpg" ;

  // Download the file using windows function into DownloadURL folder
  URLDownloadToFile (nullptr,FileURL[2],TargetURL,0,nullptr) ; // OK

  // Download the file using curl library into DownloadCURL folder
  if (auto curl = curl_easy_init ()) {
      auto fp = fopen (TargetCURL,"wb") ;
      curl_easy_setopt (curl,CURLOPT_URL,FileURL[1]) ;
      curl_easy_setopt (curl,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1) ;
      curl_easy_setopt (curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,fp) ;

      /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
      auto res = curl_easy_perform (curl) ;                     // Always Fail

      fclose (fp) ;
      curl_easy_cleanup (curl) ;
  } /* if (auto curl = curl_easy_init ()) */

  return true ;

} /* Download */
```

My system is running Windows 10 x64. I use Visual Studio 2017, Libcurl revision 7.67 with openSSL.

Can anyone help me figure out what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you use redirects to this URL:
`https://images.pexels.com/photos/618608/pexels-photo-618608.jpeg?cs=srgb&amp;dl=worm-s-eyeview-of-tall-tree-under-a-gray-sky-618608.jpg&amp;fm=jpg` so you need to enable following redirects in curl:

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);  // follow redirects`

You also need to supply the `write_data` function:

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);`

And
`curl_easy_setopt (curl,CURLOPT_URL,FileURL[1]) ;`
should be
`curl_easy_setopt (curl,CURLOPT_URL,FileURL);`

If you are behind a http proxy, you may also need
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1L);`

```
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include <cstdio>

static size_t write_data(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, static_cast<FILE*>(stream));
    return written;
} /* write_data */

bool DownloadFile() {
    bool retval = false;
    static const char FileURL[] =
        "https://www.pexels.com/photo/618608/download/"
        "?search_query=park&tracking_id=6qgsqm6nzau";
    static char TargetCURL[] = "D:\\Download\\DownloadCURL\\Test.jpg";

    // Download the file using curl library into DownloadCURL folder
    if(CURL* curl = curl_easy_init()) {
        if(FILE* fp = fopen(TargetCURL, "wb")) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, FileURL);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L); // follow redirects
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1L); // corp. proxies etc.

            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            if(!res) retval = true;

            fclose(fp);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    } /* if (auto curl = curl_easy_init ()) */

    return retval;

} /* Download */

int main() {
    CURLcode res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    if(res) return 1;
    DownloadFile();
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

Comment: I added this line and also one line I missed to post in my original question curl_easy_setopt (curl,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,write_data) ; However I still receive the same error.

Comment: @makhlouf The full example above works for me. Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Yes I still have the same error. Did you actually downloaded the photo? If so, it means the library I built is not functioning.

Comment: @makhlouf Yes, I ran the program above and got the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The error is about TLS certificate issuer validation. You're missing the CA cert for the server. On Windows OpenSSL by default comes with an empty cert store. On Windows is better to compile libcurl with schannel support instead of OpenSSL, then it'll use the Windows built-in cert store.

Comment: I am not familiar with server certificates. Can you give me more information about schannel support. The options I found while building the Libcurl were with :NGHTTP2, MBEDTLS, CARES, ZLIB, SSH2.

Comment: I rebuilt the Libcurl library without openSSL support. The program works and it actually downloaded the file. I searched my windows directory and found it already contains schannel.dll file. So all I needed was to remove the OpenSSL from Libcurl. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, schannel is a built-in Windows component. Lubcurl will use it by default, if no other SSL library is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need set these options：

```
curl_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

---

Maybe you can try [teemo](https://github.com/winsoft666/teemo) library, it based libcurl, and support multi-thread download